# In Win7, executing a program from shared drive unable to get correct proxy

Tags: windows-7, proxy

In company I have a shared drive potentially in another domain.
The computer use proxy via the auto configuration script and that is configured via Internet Explorer.

If I put program e.g. putty.exe in the local disk, I am able to connect to the Internet.
However if I put that in the shared drive and execute from there, it is not able to connect. with error gethostname failed.

[This page](http://andrewbevitt.com/2010/02/04/putty-gethostbyname-unknown-error/) also suggest copying to local solved the issue

I found this issue is not specific to putty, but also for other programs e.g. eclipse.

What is the mechanism for program to get the proxy when executed in shared drive?
How to work around besides copying it into local disk?

Comment: Internet Explorer's security 'zone' settings affect network drives. That is the mechanism, and where you can look to change it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for promot response. I believe you mean the settings in IE, securtiy-> Local intranet , to uncheck "Include all network path"? Unfortunately I do not have admin right to change this in my company. Any workaround are greatly appreciated.